# Array comparison using string element

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I should use currenttest value to find the current location in testorder array. I need to start from that index and advance, looking for trueVitals availability. Any help would be much appreciated. Downside right now in current code is it is hard to exhaustively test every code path in the function "if(mode == "bpw" & currenttest == "ECG")"

```
var json_data = {
  "Blood Pressure": true,
  "Weight Scale": true,
  "Body Composition": true,
  "ECG": true,
  "SPO2": false,
  "temp": true
};

var hardwarelist = [];
var testorder = ["Blood Pressure", "Weight Scale", "Body Composition", "ECG", "SPo2", "temp"];

for (var i in json_data) {
  hardwarelist.push([i, json_data[i]]);
}

var trueVitals = hardwarelist.filter(([, e]) => e).map(([e]) => e);
var mode = "bpw";
var currenttest = "ECG";
nextTest(mode, currenttest);

function nextTest(mode, currenttest) {
  var currenttestorder = (testorder.indexOf(currenttest));
  if (mode == "bpw" & currenttest == "ECG") {
     if(trueVitals.includes("Weight Scale"){ 
      window.location.href = "#/about";
      }
      else if (trueVitals.includes("ECG")) {
        window.location.href = "#/services";
      } else if (trueVitals.includes("SPO2")) {
        window.location.href = "#/contact";
      } else if (trueVitals.includes("Body Composition")) {
        window.location.href = "#/blog";
      } else if (trueVitals.includes("temp")) {
        window.location.href = "#/faq";
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: is this intentionally: `if (trueVitals.includes("Weight Scale");` an empty statement?

Comment: In addition, you've also got a handful of missing `}` and `)`. It would be a bit easier for us to help you out if you touched up your snippet, thus making it runnable :)

Comment: corrected the missing syntax